# Using over adverb to operate on a table

Tags: kdb

Given a dyadic function f that takes as its arguments:

x: A keyed table
y: A key value that indicates the row to be created

And assuming that the update operations need to run serially (not a bulk operation), and once that key is populated we will ignore further updates for it:

```
q)tbl:([col1:()];col2:())
q)kv:10?`a`b`c`d
q)f:{[x;y]if[y in key[x];:x];x upsert (y;1?10)}

q)(f/)[enlist[tbl],kv]
col1| col2
----| ----
a   | 9
b   | 2
c   | 1
d   | 8
```

Is there a more correct way to construct the call?  Mixing the two inputs into a single input list feels a little like a hack, and raises questions about how to accommodate functions that take more than 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs a small tweak :

```
q)(f/)[tbl;kv]
```

this is covered on the KX wiki (https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Slash)

```
/ -  f/[y] is equivalent to f[f[..f[f[y0;y1];y2];..yn-1];yn]
q)+/[1 2 3]
6
q)(f/)[enlist[tbl],kv]  /joining both arguments to a single list

/ - f/[x;y] is equivalent to f[f[..f[f[x;y0];y1];..yn-1];yn] 
q)+/[10;1 2 3]
16
q)(f/)[tbl;kv]    / here we are passing the table as first argument
```

Comment: Looks much more obvious.  I don't why I didn't try it before the enlist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps running upsert on the distinct input is more efficient?

```
(tbl upsert)/[flip(d;(count d:distinct kv)?10)]
```